# jqGrid multiple row selection advanced

Tags: jqgrid

I want the following ability in jqGrid.
When a user clicks on the checkbox in the grid a row is selected.
When the user subsequently clicks "Control key" and selects the checkbox the user can subsequently select more no of rows. Then when user clicks on the checkbox and if the current row is selected, the current row is then selected. Is this possible with jqGrid?
However nothing should happen when cells are are clicked. Only events should be available from  checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should be possible. Take a look at the normal example for [checkbox selection](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) - it gets you part of the way there. It doesn't really handle the SHIFT select stuff the way you'd expect, though.

I did some searching and found this code on the jqGrid support site:

```
function multiSelectHandler(sid, e) {
    var grid = $(e.target).closest("table.ui-jqgrid-btable");
    var ts = grid[0], td = e.target;
    var scb = $(td).hasClass("cbox");
    if ((td.tagName == 'INPUT' && !scb) || td.tagName == 'A') {
        return true;
    }
    var sel = grid.getGridParam('selarrrow');
    var selected = $.inArray(sid, sel) >= 0;
    if (e.ctrlKey || (scb && (selected || !e.shiftKey))) {
        grid.setSelection(sid,true);
    } else {
        if (e.shiftKey) {
            var six = grid.getInd(sid);
            var min = six, max = six;
            $.each(sel, function() {
                    var ix = grid.getInd(this);
                    if (ix < min) min = ix;
                    if (ix > max) max = ix;
                });
            while (min <= max) {
                var row = ts.rows[min++];
                var rid = row.id;
                if (rid != sid && $.inArray(rid, sel)<0) {
                    grid.setSelection(row.id, false);
                }
            }
        } else if (!selected) {
            grid.resetSelection();
        }
        if (!selected) {
            grid.setSelection(sid,true);
        } else {
            var osr = grid.getGridParam('onSelectRow');
            if ($.isFunction(osr)) {
                osr(sid, true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To use it, you're supposed to be able to set the beforeSelectRow handler to this function. Ex. something like this:

```
$("#gridid").jqGrid({
// Rest of code to configure grid
beforeSelectRow: multiSelectHandler,
// Other handlers/configuration
});
```

Comment: @Oleg A question you may already have encountered...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10552867/jqgrid-advanced-search-dialog-column-which-has-dropdown-selection