# jqGrid Advanced Search dialog - column which has dropdown selection

Tags: jqgrid

I have a jqGrid 4.3.1 with Advanced filter. some of the columns which are boolean types like Yes/No types, I show a dropdown when the column type is selected when a new advanced filter row is created.
E.g. Say column 2 is IsActive (Boolean) type and when this is selected I shown a drop down instead of the textbox. 
The code which overrides the jqGrid advanced filter is as follows:

```
var cols = grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel");
for (var i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {
if (cols[i].stype && cols[i].stype == "select" && cols[i].searchoptions && cols[i].searchoptions.buildSelect && $.isFunction(cols[i].searchoptions.buildSelect)
&& !cols[i].searchoptions.dataUrl && !cols[i].searchoptions.value) {
cols[i].searchoptions.value = cols[i].searchoptions.buildSelect(null);
}
```

This code used to work fine in 4.3 version (one version before 4.3.1)
Don't know what is causing the problem but now my dropdowns appear blank.
Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You don't posted the code of `buildSelect` which you use, so it's difficult to say why the code fail. What I don't understand mostly is why you has so complex code at all. If you know that the column `IsActive` has type Boolean and you want display it in the Advance Searching dialog as drop-down having "Yes" and "No" values and display it in grid and during editing as checkbox you can do the following:

```js
{ name: "IsActive", template: myCheckboxTemplate }
```

where `mytemplateCheckbox` you define like

```js
var myCheckboxTemplate = {
        formatter: "checkbox", align: "center", width: 20,
        edittype: "checkbox", editoptions: { value: "1:0" },
        stype: "select", searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne"], value: "1:Yes;0:No" }
    };
```

The described approach I use permanently and it works very well. The only difference from the code above is that I use ["clickableCheckbox"](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/make-disabled-checkbox-of-the-checkbox-formatter-clickable/#p25668) formatter instead of "checkbox". If you want you can download it from [here](https://github.com/OlegKi/jqGrid-plugins).

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have added a new question which I am really struggling with..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10579864/jqgrid-column-selector-inline-rather-than-in-dialog

Comment: my build select function maps to a function which has the folowing implementation return ": All; true: True; false:False";

Comment: @chugh97: Which sense has to get static data from the server (from URL `dataUrl`) and then convert there to the select with static values? Moreover `buildSelect` have to produce HTML fragment `<select><option value="true">True</option><option value="false">False</option></select>` instead of string like `": All; true: True; false:False"` used as the value of `value` property. The usage of `: All;` inside of Searching Dialog is also not good. All seems very strange...