# jqGrid - column selector inline rather than in dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have ui-multiselect plugin and it renders the column selector in a dialog. I want it to render inline inside the jqGrid. How can this be done.

Comment: Sorry, but from the current question it's not quite clear what you do. Some more description, more pictures, more code would be clear what you do or you plan to do. Probably you use *another* ui-multiselect plugin as the columnChooser uses (see [here](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/) for example)?

Comment: I have been using this plugin but it pops up in a jquery-ui-dialog. I want it inside the HTML dom. Is this possible?

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand you. Which one from two ui-multiselect plugins you use? Do you use `columnChooser` and so the `ui.multiselect.js` from `plugins` subdirectory of jqGrid or you use UI MultiSelect Widget written by Eric Hynds (see [the demos](http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/))? What you mean under "inside the HTML dom"? Where you want integrate on your page the "column selector" and what you exactly mean? You use words "column **selector**" in the text of your question. Do you want to use `columnChooser` or some CSS selectors of columns?

Comment: @Oleg I am using the ui-multiselect written by Eric Hynds if that helps. I want this to be rendered in inside the html dom rather than a dialog

Comment: I still have no idea what you want to do. The words "this to be rendered in inside the html dom" say me nothing. What render? Every element on the page are represented by DOM, so "inside the html dom" means not more as on the page. In which place on the page, grid or part of the grid (Searching dialog, Filter toolbar, Form editing, Inline editing,...)? I see the only way to go forward if you append your question with *more detailed information* about your problem. You can use UI MultiSelect Widget (by Eric Hynds) in many different ways. So you should **detailed** describe what you want to do.

Comment: Do you want integrate UI MultiSelect Widget in the Searching Toolbar or you need something other?